# How to use Spring ResourceUrlEncodingFilter with velocity template

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

[Spring boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) suggest that velocity templates have support for `ResourceUrlEncodingFilter` for rewriting static assets url with versioning. Quote from the docs:

> Links to resources are rewritten at runtime in template, thanks to a ResourceUrlEncodingFilter, auto-configured for Thymeleaf, Velocity and FreeMarker.

I found out from [this blog](http://www.mscharhag.com/spring/resource-versioning-with-spring-mvc) the syntax for thymeleaf for url rewriting. But after spending a couple of hours of google searching I wasn't able to find the syntax or macros for Velocity templating language. Can anyone point me to a resource which explains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, see [SPR-14027](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14027).
In the meantime, you can define your own macro like this:

```
#macro( springResourceUrl $relativeUrl )$springMacroRequestContext.getContextUrl(${relativeUrl})#end
```

And call it like this:

```
<script src="#springResourceUrl("/script.js")"></script>
```

Note that Velocity support is deprecated as of Spring 4.3 (see [SPR-13235](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13235)) and should be removed in Spring 5.0 (see [SPR-13795](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13795)).